# Product Catalgoue

Tags: cms, ecommerce, windows-server, product-management

I am looking for a product catalogue software.

The most important aspect to me is: Windows Server/IIS compatible.

It should be multi-language capable and have good ways to import data from another system.

So it is basically an online shop without the need of a shopping basket or payment system.

**Update:** Is magento a good solution for my scenario?

Comment: Import data from **which** other system?

Comment: It is a proprietary system we could then extend to push the data into the product catalogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> basically an online shop without the need of a shopping basket or
>   payment system

You *could* choose a CMS at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/ to meet your exact needs.

**But**,if all that you want is truly only "an online shop without the need of a shopping basket or payment system" then, IMO, you can't beat [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/), which is extremely popular, extremely powerful, but still capable of being used by not too tech-savvy users and which can still quickly generate a site.

For a product catalog, see [Setting up a Product Catalog](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/setting-product-catalog), or consider the [Spider Catalog](https://www.drupal.org/project/spider_catalog) module.

> Spider Catalog is one of the best Drupal Product Catalog modules
>   available. It is an effective tool for building product catalogs. It
>   is highly customizable and has a clear and easy-to-use back-end
>   interface.

You can find a demo [here](http://drupaldemo.web-dorado.com/spider-catalog-cell-view).